# Having troubles creating an HTTP GET request via Java

Tags: java, http, networking, backend

At the moment I'm trying to create a HTTP GET request, assign multiple parameters, then read the plain text file output from the GET request. What I'm currently trying to use is the HTTPClient library provided Java, I'll attach relevant code below as well as the current error I'm running into.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEYd4.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAvH4.png)

"announceURL" is the url I'm trying to send the request to. Below I'll add an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[URL Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5KUf.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Rather than using links to image captures of your code and compiler errors, could you copy/paste them directly into your question? This will improve the odds of your question being answered quickly and it will also help other users find help with similar errors/code. Please edit your question and use the "code" formatting ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever considered using Apache `HttpClient`? Code Snippet Attached below seems to work on your mentioned endpoint. Hope this helps.

**P.S:** You'll have to add this library as a Maven dependency in your pom.xml. [Link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.10) here.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class API {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://mirror.rackspace.com/archlinux/iso/2019.12.01");
        URI uri = new URIBuilder(request.getURI())
                .setParameter("info_hash", "foo")
                .setParameter("peer_id", "bar")
                .build();
        request.setURI(uri);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String content = IOUtils.toString(input);
        System.out.println(content);
    }
}
```

**Response:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /archlinux/iso/2019.12.01</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /archlinux/iso/2019.12.01</h1>
<ul><li><a href="/archlinux/iso/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
<li><a href="arch/"> arch/</a></li>
<li><a href="archlinux-2019.12.01-x86_64.iso"> archlinux-2019.12.01-x86_64.iso</a></li>
<li><a href="archlinux-2019.12.01-x86_64.iso.sig"> archlinux-2019.12.01-x86_64.iso.sig</a></li>
<li><a href="archlinux-2019.12.01-x86_64.iso.torrent"> archlinux-2019.12.01-x86_64.iso.torrent</a></li>
<li><a href="archlinux-bootstrap-2019.12.01-x86_64.tar.gz"> archlinux-bootstrap-2019.12.01-x86_64.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="archlinux-bootstrap-2019.12.01-x86_64.tar.gz.sig"> archlinux-bootstrap-2019.12.01-x86_64.tar.gz.sig</a></li>
<li><a href="md5sums.txt"> md5sums.txt</a></li>
<li><a href="sha1sums.txt"> sha1sums.txt</a></li>
</ul>
Rackers - More on this mirror here: https://rax.io/mirrorfaq
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.demo;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JavaHttpClientExample {

    // one instance, reuse
    private final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
            .build();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JavaHttpClientExample obj = new JavaHttpClientExample();

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        obj.sendGet();

        System.out.println("Testing 2 - Send Http POST request");
        obj.sendPost();

    }

    private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .uri(URI.create("https://httpbin.org/get"))
                .setHeader("User-Agent", "Java 11 HttpClient Bot")
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        // print status code
        System.out.println(response.statusCode());

        // print response body
        System.out.println(response.body());

    }

    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        // form parameters
        Map<Object, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("username", "abc");
        data.put("password", "123");
        data.put("custom", "secret");
        data.put("ts", System.currentTimeMillis());

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .POST(buildFormDataFromMap(data))
                .uri(URI.create("https://httpbin.org/post"))
                .setHeader("User-Agent", "Java 11 HttpClient Bot") // add request header
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        // print status code
        System.out.println(response.statusCode());

        // print response body
        System.out.println(response.body());

    }

    private static HttpRequest.BodyPublisher buildFormDataFromMap(Map<Object, Object> data) {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                builder.append("&");
            }
            builder.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey().toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            builder.append("=");
            builder.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue().toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
        return HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(builder.toString());
    }

}
```